# A good 3V single supply OpAmp recommendation for a transimpedance amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have designed a transimpedance amplifier using [OPA355](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa355.pdf), the datasheet suggest this Opamp can go down to 2.5V and still works however I cannot get it to work at 3V. If I provide 5V supply, everything works, when I reduce to 3V, things stop working.

I will further debug this but I am looking for a reliable 3V single supply OpAmp that I will use as a transimpedance amplifier. My signal is about 3MHz and I deal with small signals so I need something with relatively low noise.

I need help from the masters as I am looking for a proven part that somebody here made it work before as opposed to perfect datasheet part.

Comment: Please post your schematic. TI doesn't generally lie on their datasheets, so maybe there's a way to get the OPA355 working for you at 3V.

Comment: As well as the schematic, defining "things stop working" would be useful too.

Comment: Yes, this sounds more like a circuit problem than the opamp working at 2.5V by mysteriously not at 3V.

Comment: I had a 2.5v bias on the + port, at 3.3v opamp doesnt like it. When I reduce the bias to 1.5 things start to work. Thanks guys. I will do more tests and let you know of interesting stuff comes up.

Comment: You are not respecting the common-mode range of the op-amp. Please post your circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the OPA355 input common mode range extends to 0.1 Volt below ground BUT only to within 1.5V of Vdd.  We'd need to see your circuit to know if this was significant. Also Vout is "not quite" rail to rail.
  [OPA355 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2355.pdf)

I'll not claim to be a master in this context, but the following may be useful:

Similar specs to OPA355in many areas.
 Apparently much superior CMRR.
 2.75 vs 5.8 nV/Hz^2
 Similar GBW
 Superior output voltage swing (especially +ve)
 280 vs 360 V/uS slew  (ie slower)

---

LTC6252 [Datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/625234fb.pdf)
 720 MHz GBW
 400MHz -3dB point as buffer
 Input common mode rail to rail.
 2.5V to 5.25V operation and fully specified at 2.7V and 5V.
 CMRR 105 dB ! (!!!!!)
 Noise 2.7 nV.Hz^-2
 280 V/uS slew :-)  :-)  :-)  :-)  :-)
 $4.59/1 in stock Digikey (Cheap considering spec).
  Single, dual and quad versions available.

[image]

Comment: You got it Russell.